# Clarification of this statement on image charges?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, boundary-conditions

I am currently studying the uniqueness theorems and their applications in electrostatics. I then came across a problem which mentions:

"The standard electrical image method fails because the image charge would be in the same region of space where we look for the solution."

Can someone please break this down for me? So far, I only understand that the uniqueness theorem places constraints on the potential in all space, apart from that I have no clue what this statement is referring to. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are studying the electric potential on a region of the space. Call this region $V$. What you normally have is a distribution of charges within $V$ and some boundary conditions on $V$'s boundary. The image method is a method to simplify such a problems by placing image charges outside $V$ such that the boundary conditions are satisfied. Therefore, if you put a charge in $V$ you are modifying the problem! But there is no trouble at all if you put them outside.